# Z/OS DB2 / QMF SQL Query - 'Having', 'Sum', Case'

Tags: sql, db2

I inherited a query that needs modifying.  The query seems standard with a 'Select field1, field2 from TABLE_A where blah, blah, blah....'

Then it has the following statements as a part of the query:

```
HAVING (SUM(CASE                                          
           WHEN S.LVLP1 NOT IN ('A','B','C','D')  THEN 1  
           ELSE 0 END)                                    
     + SUM(CASE                                           
           WHEN S.LVLP1 IN('A','B','C','D') THEN 1        
           ELSE 0 END)                                    
     ¬= SUM(CASE                                          
           WHEN S.LVLP1 NOT IN('A','B','C','D') THEN 1    
           ELSE 0 END))                                   
AND SUM(CASE                                              
       WHEN S.LVLP1 IN('A','B','C','D') THEN 1            
       ELSE 0 END) > 0
```

I cannot understand what the SUM(CASE) statements are doing.  They seem redundant, but it's a query that's been used for sometime.  Can someone please shed some light on what these statements are accomplishing?  Thank you.

Comment: what is the sign   ¬=  ???

Comment: the code filter the reult of an aggregated  query .. based on condition  ..

Comment: ' ¬= ' means 'not equal'. I do not understand your answer about aggregated query. I guess I need it in more 'layman' terms.

Comment: in your code there several aspect to eval  .. whats your real problem  .. the use of having? .. the sum of case  ?  the logical comparision between part of code .. ?? ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SUM(CASE                                          
    WHEN S.LVLP1 NOT IN ('A','B','C','D')  THEN 1  
    ELSE 0 END)
```

counts number of rows in the group where `S.LVLP1` is not one of 'A','B','C','D'.

```
 SUM(CASE                                           
     WHEN S.LVLP1 IN('A','B','C','D') THEN 1        
     ELSE 0 END)
```

counts number of rows in the group where `S.LVLP1` *is* one of 'A','B','C','D'.

```
 ¬= SUM(CASE                                          
       WHEN S.LVLP1 NOT IN('A','B','C','D') THEN 1    
       ELSE 0 END))
```

compares the sum of "not A, B, C, D rows" and "A, B, C, D rows" with the sum of just "not A, B, C, D rows" -- the result will be true if there are some "A, B, C, D rows", all numbers being non-negative.

This

```
AND SUM(CASE                                              
   WHEN S.LVLP1 IN('A','B','C','D') THEN 1            
   ELSE 0 END) > 0
```

is also true if there are some "A, B, C, D rows". Looks like the two conditions are attempting to do the same thing and therefore one is redundant.

Overall the condition is equivalent to this correlated subquery

```
HAVING EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 FROM yourtable T
  WHERE T.LVLP1 IN('A','B','C','D')
  AND (your grouping columns in T) = (grouping columns from the outer select S)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the goal is to take grouping lines for which not all lines contain only A, B, C or D. (and exclude null values)

You can simplify the query like that I think:

```
HAVING count(S.LVLP1)<> SUM(CASE WHEN S.LVLP1 NOT IN('A','B','C','D') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
```